# Replace and Contains not recognizing the string

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to strip the country code off the phone number and place it in the textbox txtMobile. cCode is just an empty string.

`GlobalsFSiA.COUNTRY_CODES.Split(",")`    contains +44 and +353.

The phone number I am testing with is +353861234567

```
For Each code As String In GlobalsFSiA.COUNTRY_CODES.Split(",")
    If objEmployee.MobilePhone.Contains(code) Then
       cCode = code
    End If
Next
Dim number As String = objEmployee.MobilePhone.Replace(cCode, "0")
txtMobile.Text = number
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: No error but the cCode is not being set and if I set is myself the replace method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to search for What is actually the split() method is used for and also difference between [split()](http://vb.net-informations.com/string/vb.net_String_Split.htm) and [substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

I think Substring() is more suitable in this scenario, you can code like this for extracting country code from the given number:

```
    Dim mobileNumber As String = "+353861234567"
    Dim countryCode As String = mobileNumber.Substring(0, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

using this code I do get the correct result

```
Dim sTest As String = "+353861234567"
Dim cCode As String = ""

Dim numbers As New List(Of String)()
numbers.Add("+44")
numbers.Add("+353")

For Each code As String In numbers
    If sTest.Contains(code) Then
        cCode = code
    End If
Next
Dim number As String = sTest.Replace(cCode, "0")
```

Is the cCode declared internally? Might be an option to take the value from the object before parsing it

Comment: Glad to hear! Don't forget to mark as Resolved if you're satisfied. It might help other users :)